# Help on the two "separate" definitions of Product Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X_{1},\mathcal{A}_{1},\mu_{1})$ and $(X_{2},\mathcal{A}_{2},\mu_{2})$ be $\sigma-$finite measures, then there exists one $\sigma-$finite measure $\pi:=\mu_{1}\otimes \mu_{2}$ on $\mathcal{A}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{2}$ (i.e. the product measure) such that

$1.$ $\mu_{1}\otimes \mu_{2}(A_{1}\times A_{2})=\mu_{1}(A_{1})\mu_{2}(A_{2})$ for any $A_{1} \in \mathcal{A}_{1}, A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}_{2}$

$2.$ Then $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{2}:\int_{X_{1}}\mu_{2}(A_{x_{1}})d\mu_{1}(x_{1})=\int_{X_{2}}\mu_{1}(A_{x_{2}})d\mu_{2}(x_{2})$

I struggle to find how $1.$ and $2.$ are related to each other. I mean the only difference I see is that in $1.$ we are looking at $A_{1} \in \mathcal{A}_{1}, A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}_{2}$ rather than $A \in \mathcal{A}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{2}$. What important concept am I missing here? Is $1.$ simply a special case of $2.$ since $\mathcal{A}_{1}\times \mathcal{A}_{2}\subseteq \mathcal{A}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{2}$, as $\mathcal{A}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{2}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$Algebra such that the projection map is measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual product measure is given in (2).

If a measure on $\mathcal{A_1} \otimes \mathcal{A_2}$ satisfies (1), then there is only one such measure and it is given by the formula in (2).

So both things yield the same thing: a description of the unique product measure.

Comment: And my assertion that $\mathcal{A_{1}}\times \mathcal{A_{2}} \subseteq \mathcal{A_{1}}\otimes \mathcal{A_{2}}$ is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. In fact,  $\mathcal{A_1} \otimes \mathcal{A_2}$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the "measurable rectangles" $\mathcal{A_1} \times \mathcal{A}_2$

Comment: But what other sets are there in $\mathcal{A_{1}}\otimes \mathcal{A_{2}}$ that are not in $\mathcal{A_{1}}\times \mathcal{A_{2}}$?

Comment: Do you know what the notation $\sigma(\mathcal{T})$ means (smallest sigma algebra generated by tau).

Comment: Yes, the smallest $\sigma-$algebra generated by the topology (i.e. the open sets)

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean to denote a topology with $\mathcal{T}$ though. Did you already prove that $\mathcal{A_1} \otimes \mathcal{A_2} = \sigma(\mathcal{A_1} \times \mathcal{A_2})$?

Comment: Yes, but that still does not give me an idea of which sets lie in $\mathcal{A}_{1}\otimes \mathcal{A}_{2} - \mathcal{A}_{1}\times \mathcal{A}_{2}$

Comment: It will depend on the sigma algebra's involved and a precise description will not be possible in general. But intuitively every set that you can make with (countably many) $\cap, \cup, ^c$ of the generating set will be in the sigma-algebra.